# Insert into Oracle XMLType Table

Tags: python, oracle

I am using python to insert data into XMLType table using cx_Oracle

```
import cx_Oracle
import pprint

db = cx_Oracle.connect('scott','tiger','localhost:1521/orcl1')
cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.setinputsizes(xml_clob=cx_Oracle.CLOB)
cursor.execute("insert into xmltable values  (xmltype(:xml_clob))",xml_clob='<name>Kathy   Smith</name>')

cursor.setinputsizes(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
cursor.prepare('insert into xmltable values (xmltype(:1))')
xml_clob = '<name>Kathy Smith</name>'
cursor.execute(None,(xml_clob))
```

ultimately i would like to insert from a list using cursor_executemany.

**This works**

```
 cursor.execute("insert into xmltable values  (xmltype(:xml_clob))",xml_clob='<name>Kathy   Smith</name>')
```

**And this doesn't**

```
----> 1 cursor.execute(None,(xml_clob))

DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

My xml file contains many records like below which i would be reading into a list and using executemany

```
<customerinfo xmlns:ns0="http://posample.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Cid="1000">
<name>Kathy Smith</name>
<addr country="Canada">
<street>5 Rosewood</street>
<city>Toronto</city>
<prov-state>Ontario</prov-state>
<pcode-zip>M6W 1E6</pcode-zip>
</addr>
<contacts>
<phone type="work">416-555-1358</phone>
<emails>
<email1>kathy@stackoverflow.org</email1>
<email2>kathy@stackover.org</email2>
</emails>
<phone type="personal">416-555-1358</phone>
 <emails>
 <email1>kathy@stackoverflow.org</email1>
<email2>kathy@stackover.org</email2>
</emails>
</contacts>
</customerinfo>
```

Comment: What is your XML? Woes it have a proper header/structure? Could you post it (or any sample XML which has same problem) here?

Comment: Well when i use bfilename and load it the xml does get inserted so i dont think so this is an issue with the xml file per se